# Remove outliers from a list of points in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, outliers

**Problem**

I have a list of points in C# that I draw on a panel on a Windows Forms object. The lists variables are two `listA` and `listB`. The points in `listB` are the points in `listA` except that they have gone through some transformation to deform it to resemble the shape formed by points in `listA` and then added some outliers to make them look different. If you can try these on your visual studio then this is the code...

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    //declare the list to hold points for 
    //shapes
    List<Point> listA = new List<Point>();
    List<Point> listB = new List<Point>();

    //this methods transforms,applies outliers and draws the shapes on panel1
    private void button1_click(EventArgs e, object sender)
    {
        //clear the lists for initializing
        listA.Clear();
        listB.Clear();
        Point p1a = new Point(20, 30);
        Point p2a = new Point(120, 50);
        Point p3a = new Point(160, 80);
        Point p4a = new Point(180, 300);
        Point p5a = new Point(100, 220);
        Point p6a = new Point(50, 280);
        Point p7a = new Point(20, 140);
        //Hold the Points in an array
        Point[] mypoints = new Point[] { p1a, p2a, p3a, p4a, p5a, p6a, p7a };
        //add the points to the List with one call
        listA.AddRange(mypoints);
        //define a new Transformation 
        //that will translate shapeA to have a slightly different imageB 
        Transformation t2 = new Transformation();
        t2.A = 1.05; t2.B = 0.05; t2.T1 = 15; t2.T2 = 22;
        //assign the new translated points to listB  
        listB = applytransformation(t2, listA);
        //Add outliers to listb by manipulating the values in the list
        Shape2[2] = new Point(Shape2[2].X + 10, Shape2[2].Y + 3);
        //create a new instance of pen
        //for drawing imageA in blue
        Pen penner = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 3);
        //Create a new instance of pen for 
        //drawing imageB in red
        Pen mypen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3);
        //get the graphic context
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        //draw both shapes
        DisplayShape(listA, penner, g);
        DisplayShape(listB, mypen, g);
    }
    //the method below does the transformation of imagea into imageb by manipulating the points and the transformation
    List<Point> applytransformation(Transformation x, List<Point> shape)
    {
        List<Point> Tlist = new List<Point>();
        foreach (Point c in shape) {
            double xprime = x.A * c.X + x.B * c.Y + x.T1;
            double yprime = x.B * c.X * -1 + x.A * c.Y + x.T2;
            Point ptrans = new Point((int)xprime, (int)yprime);

            Tlist.Add(ptrans);
        }
        //it returns the points that will be used to draw imageB
        return Tlist;
    }
    //this method draws the points on the panel
    void DisplayShape(List<Point> Shp, Pen pen, Graphics G)
    {
        Point? prevPoint = null;//nullable
        foreach (Point pt in Shp) {
            G.DrawEllipse(pen, new Rectangle(pt.X - 2, pt.Y - 2, 4, 4));
            if (prevPoint != null) {
                G.DrawLine(pen, (Point)prevPoint, pt);

            }
            prevPoint = pt;

        }
        G.DrawLine(pen, Shp[0], Shp[Shp.Count - 1]);

    }
}
public class Transformation
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public double T1 { get; set; }
    public double T2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Goal**

I want to remove all the outliers in imageB so that it resembles imageA even if it won't be perfect. All methods or algorithms are welcome ie `RANSAC,minimum cost function`. I have tried to find an authoritative source online that can guide or help me achieve this in C# with zero success. The code I have provided is a minimum reproducible example that can be replicated on any visual studio IDE.Please help, Thank You for your time and contribution.

**Expected Output**

I added an image to make it clear the result I want
[image]

Comment: Why have the two points on the top right been replaced by one? The outlier seems to be the spike pointing to the bottom right. And why are there already two lines before applying the transformation?

Comment: Yeah the bottom right spike is an outlier, I got a code in ransac to check for error points and remove them

Answer (score 0):

If you have many points forming a cloud of points where the line defining the shape goes through, then you can remove outliers. As an example see Removing outliers. But in this case, every point in the list seems to be a vertex of the shape. Removing a point will alter the shape considerably.

Can you explain what these shapes represent? hat should happen if you remove an outlier? Should it be replaced by another point?

While this is not an answer to your question, here is an improved and simplified version of the code:

```cs
List<Point> listA, listB; // Initialization not required.

private void button1_click(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
    // Simplify initialization with collection and object initializers.
    listA = new List<Point> {
        new Point(20, 30), new Point(120, 50),
        new Point(160, 80), new Point(180, 300),
        new Point(100, 220), new Point(50, 280),
        new Point(20, 140)
    };
    var t2 = new Transformation { A = 1.05, B = 0.05, T1 = 15, T2 = 22 };

    listB = ApplyTransformation(t2, listA);

    // Simplify shifting point.
    Shape2[2] += new Size(10, 3);

    // Invalidate panel and let Panel1_Paint draw it.
    // Never create your own Graphics object.
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (listA != null && listB != null) {
        // Use predefined pens instead of creating brushes.
        DisplayShape(listA, Pens.Blue, e.Graphics);
        DisplayShape(listB, Pens.Red, e.Graphics);
    }
}

List<Point> ApplyTransformation(Transformation x, List<Point> shape)
{
    // Prevent list resizing by specifying initial size.
    var transformedList = new List<Point>(shape.Count);
    foreach (Point c in shape) {
        double xprime = x.A * c.X + x.B * c.Y + x.T1;
        double yprime = x.B * c.X * -1 + x.A * c.Y + x.T2;
        transformedList.Add(new Point((int)xprime, (int)yprime));
    }
    return transformedList;
}

void DisplayShape(List<Point> shape, Pen pen, Graphics g)
{
    // By using "for" instead of "foreach" we have indexes we can use to
    // simplify closing the shape, since we always have a previous point.
    for (int i = 0; i < shape.Count; i++) {
        Point prevPoint = i > 0 ? shape[i - 1] : shape[shape.Count - 1];
        Point pt = shape[i];

        // No need to create a rectangle,
        // there is an overload accepting location and size.
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, pt.X - 2, pt.Y - 2, 4, 4);

        g.DrawLine(pen, prevPoint, pt);
    }
}
```

Since C# 8.0 and in .NET Core projects we can also write `shape[^1]` to get the last point instead of `shape[shape.Count - 1]`.

Comment: Yes it should be replaced by another point that is close to it

Comment: This is really helpful,  the point that is an outlier needs to e replaced by a close point

Comment: Those shapes are images. I need to perform an outlier removal on the second image to make it look like A but not exactly